# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params').trying to get params from url params

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get the URL params inside a Card class component in order to display it:

```
import React from "react";

class  Card extends React.Component {

    state = { user :''}

    componentDidMount(){
        let user = this.props.match.params.user
        this.setState({ user : user})
    }


    render() {
        const { user } = this.state

        return(
            <div >
            <h3 className="ui header">{user}</h3>


        </div>
        )
    }
}
```

the App.js file

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes, Outlet  } from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from "./componenets/NavBar";
import Home from "./componenets/Home";
import Contact from "./componenets/Contact";
import About from "./componenets/About";
import Card from "./componenets/Card";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<About/>} />
          <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact/>} />
          <Route exact path="card/:user" element ={<Card/>} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
export default App;
```

and the index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

and this is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-router",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router": "^6.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

so when I start the react app and try to go the path http://localhost:3000/card/choosenName
I expect the 'chosenName' to paper in the card instead I get this error in the Browserconsole

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')
    at Card.componentDidMount (Card.js:9:1)
    at commitLifeCycles (react-dom.development.js:20663:1)
    at commitLayoutEffects (react-dom.development.js:23426:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
    at commitRootImpl (react-dom.development.js:23151:1)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:468:1)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276:1)
    at commitRoot (react-dom.development.js:22990:1)
```

Comment: `exact` prop is not supported in v6 of react-router. Also, hooks   and functional components are preferred, i.e. `useParams()`. Also `path="card/:user"` is a relative path but defined on a `<Route>` that is not nested.

Comment: so instead of a class component, I should change it to a function component?

Answer (score 0):

In `react-router-dom` v6 there are no longer any route props, so no history, location, or match props are passed from route to component. In fact, if you look at the JSX it should be quite clear that no props are being passed to `Card`. You have to use `useParams()`.

```
function Card() {
  let user = useParams();
  console.log(user);
  return(
    <div
      className='ui raised very padded text container segment'
      style={{ marginTop: '80px' }}
    >
      <h3 className='ui header'>Card</h3>
    </div>
  )
}
export default Card;
```